# If value is 0 then skip VBA Macro

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to get some code to print the active sheet based on the value of cell "B5" in Excel/VBA, if the value of B5 is 0 then the macro crashes and shows an error.

Is there a way to get this to just skip to the next line if the value of B5 is 0?

```
iNumCopies = Range("B5").Value
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=iNumCopies
```

Comment: It would really help if you explained what system and language this is in.

Comment: @Logarr Apologies, amended.